# Returning array of objects in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to be able to change objects on server, save those, and return results back to frontend part of application. 
So basically, I have some code that does manipulation of data, than Eloquent that does saving, and than I want to return Eloquent object back. Problem is that I have more than one object, that I'll manipulate, and right now, I'm putting all of them in array. When it comes back to my frontend all it has is this:

```
[{"incrementing":true,"timestamps":true,"exists":true}]
```

Here is the simplified code:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($tasks as $task){
 //some manipulation
 $result = Task::find($task['id']);
 $result->order = $task['order'];
 $result->save();
 $results[] = $result;
}
return Response::json($results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to call toArray() method before putting element to array.

```
$results[] = $result->toArray();
```

Comment: I had a similar situation, now it works. Still, the solution is kind of dirty and not laravel-conform. I thought it should be better to solve it with a Eloquent Collection, but didn't work well too. Probably this is something they should fix.